# Android Contact Picker Checklist

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to create a "select-multiple" contact list where I can allow a user to check more than one contact. What I'm looking for is effectively the same thing as the native activity that appears when composing a message to multiple contacts. Thanks!

Comment: Was trying with the ContactsContract stuff, but 1.6 compat would be nice. My issue is with the checkbox part. Does Android have some kind of native contact picker with checkboxes, as used in Messaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to get a list of contacts and then display it on ListView element. For example I'm using following code to display all users contacts on a ListView:

```
                 // Run query on all contacts id
                Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
                String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
                String selection = null;//ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '" + ("1") + "'";
                String[] selectionArgs = null;
                String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

                ContentResolver contectResolver = getContentResolver();

                Cursor cursor = contectResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        sortOrder);

                //Create buffer
                final ArrayList<ContactData> bufferContacts = new ArrayList<ContactData>();

                //Load contacts one by one
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {



                        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));


                        String[] emailProj = new String[]{Email.DATA};
                        Cursor cursorEmail = contectResolver.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, emailProj,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ? ", new String[] { id }, null);

                        String[] phoneProj = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};
                        Cursor cursorPhone = contectResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, phoneProj,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                        String firstName = "";
                        String lastName = "";
                        String email = "";
                        String displayname = "";
                        String phoneNmb = "";

                        if(cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
                            ///displayname = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            phoneNmb = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        }
                        cursorPhone.close();

                        if(cursorEmail.moveToFirst()) {
                            email = cursorEmail.getString(cursorEmail.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                        }
                        cursorEmail.close();

                        displayname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                        //Divide display name to first and last
                        String[] names = displayname.split("\\s+");

                        firstName = displayname;

                        if(names.length >= 1) {
                            firstName = names[0];
                        }

                        if(names.length >= 2) {
                            firstName = names[1];
                        }

                        final ContactData contactData = new ContactData(id, firstName, lastName, phoneNmb, email, allChecked);

                        bufferContacts.add(contactData);

                        //Set list view initialy
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                if(contactsAdapter == null) {
                                    ArrayList<ContactData> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactData>();
                                    contactsAdapter = new ContactAdapter(ContactPickerActivity.this, contacts);

                                    lvContacts.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);
                                }

                                if(bufferContacts.size() >= BUFFER_INTERVAL) {
                                    addBuffer(bufferContacts);
                                }
                            }

                        });

                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                }

                cursor.close();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        addBuffer(bufferContacts);

                    }

                });
```

If you don't want to bother yourself with making everything out of scratch then feel free to use my ready library for selecting multiple contacts:

https://github.com/kgadzinowski/Android-Multiple-Contacts-Picker-Library

Comment: You have not mentioned how to use your library and support gradle it will be easy to use and helpful.